# pywin32: GetFileVersionInfo returns 1812

Tags: python, windows, pywin32

I am using the pyWin32 module like this:

```
import win32api
from win32api import GetFileVersionInfo, LOWORD, HIWORD


def get_version_number (filename):
  info = win32api.GetFileVersionInfo(filename,"\\")
  ms = info['FileVersionMS']
  ls = info['FileVersionLS']
  return HIWORD (ms), LOWORD (ms), HIWORD (ls), LOWORD (ls)


if __name__ == '__main__':
   print(get_version_number ("./aa.txt"))
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\file_filter.py", line 70, in <module>
    print(get_version_number ("./aa.txt"))
  File ".\file_filter.py", line 60, in get_version_number
    info = win32api.GetFileVersionInfo(filename,"\\")
pywintypes.error: (1812, 'GetFileVersionInfo:GetFileVersionInfoSize', ...)
```

I get the above error. However it works fine for the following file: `"./python.exe"`.

Answer (score 1):

Excerpt from this reference:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647003(v=vs.85).aspx

> GetFileVersionInfo was taking version information from the binary (exe/dll). Currently, it is querying fixed version from language neutral file (exe/dll) and the non-fixed part from mui file, merges them and returns to the user.

The only available file type for GetFileVersionInfo is either *.exe or *.dll. Yet you're querying against a *.txt file.

Comment: At first, I wanted to filter the *.MTS files according to the file information. Finally, I solved it by ffprobe. Thank you for helping me.